# Error Installing github-pages gem in command line on Windows

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

I've managed to setup Ruby 1.9.3 and devkit as well as jekyll and a bunch of other gems. However, now when I try installing github-pages gem (gem install github-pages) I get the following error:

Note: I've tried running command line as an admin with no more success

Here's the output from my command line:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native
>   extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing
>   github-pages:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141208-60036-a7hzln.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make  clean Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
>
> make Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redcarpet
>   -3.1.2 for inspection. Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/re
>   dcarpet-3.1.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I couldn't find the answer on SO so I looked around elsewhere and was able to find the answer on GitHub. Please see here:

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977

Basically, if you're getting this error on Windows using RubyGems 1.9.3 (which I was) you need to downgrade to 1.8.29 until this is fixed. Glad to know it's not just me making this error!

How to downgrade, you may be asking? On Windows:

```
gem update --system 1.8.29
```

I downgraded and had no trouble installing the other gem files I needed.